# Creating multiplication table of symmetric group S_3

Tags: tables, math-mode

How one can create multiplication table of symmetric group S_3?

(In that table 6 columns and 6 rows)

Edit:

here some progress:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l|llllll}
    ~   & e   & a   & a^2 & b   & c   & d   \\
    e   & e   & a   & a^2 & b   & c   & d   \\
    a   & a   & a^2 & e   & c   & d   & b   \\
    a^2 & a^2 & e   & a   & d   & b   & c   \\
    b   & b   & d   & c   & e   & a^2 & a   \\
    c   & c   & b   & d   & a   & e   & a^2 \\
    d   & d   & c   & b   & a^2 & a   & e   \\
    \end{tabular} \end{table}
```

But now I can't figure how making the horizontal line...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Are you asking us to do that for you or you have some code that shows how you did it?

Comment: @karlkoeller: Thank you! I've edited my post.

Comment: Does adding `\hline` after your `\\ `'s do what you want?

Comment: Reading the available documentation does wonders in this sort of cases... :P

Comment: @karlkoeller, or `\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}|*{6}{>{$}l<{$}}}` which is slightly more legible.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez For sure!

Comment: Another small question: how I make that table appear in center of paper?

Comment: Add `\centering` right after `\begin{table}`

Comment: Maybe a low rep user could compile all this info into an answer including the centering information, the horizontal lines and the automatic mathmode setup.

Comment: ...and a link to one of the very many great pieces of online documentation where this information can be found.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez That as well, good suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\[
    \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}|*{6}{>{$}l<{$}}}
    ~   & e   & a   & a^2 & b   & c   & d   \\
    \hline\vrule height 12pt width 0pt
    e   & e   & a   & a^2 & b   & c   & d   \\
    a   & a   & a^2 & e   & c   & d   & b   \\
    a^2 & a^2 & e   & a   & d   & b   & c   \\
    b   & b   & d   & c   & e   & a^2 & a   \\
    c   & c   & b   & d   & a   & e   & a^2 \\
    d   & d   & c   & b   & a^2 & a   & e   \\
    \end{tabular} 
\]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Note the "invisible" `\vrule` to keep the rule clear of the superscript 2.

Here I have presented the table in a math display.  If you *really* want it in a floating table, then replace `\[` with `\begin{table}\centering` and `\]` with `\end{table}`.  Your display will then float to the top of the next page.

There's a good introduction to tables in Latex on [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

And for the curious and/or the diehards, you can do it the plain TeX way too.

```
$$\vbox{\tabskip0.5em\offinterlineskip
    \halign{\strut$#$\hfil\ \tabskip1em\vrule&&$#$\hfil\cr
    ~   & e   & a   & a^2 & b   & c   & d   \cr
    \noalign{\hrule}\vrule height 12pt width 0pt
    e   & e   & a   & a^2 & b   & c   & d   \cr
    a   & a   & a^2 & e   & c   & d   & b   \cr
    a^2 & a^2 & e   & a   & d   & b   & c   \cr
    b   & b   & d   & c   & e   & a^2 & a   \cr
    c   & c   & b   & d   & a   & e   & a^2 \cr
    d   & d   & c   & b   & a^2 & a   & e   \cr
}}$$
```

Most of the "difficulty" here is to do with having the vertical rule.  If you remove that (or replace it with some white space) you can dispense with the `\strut`s and the `\offinterlineskip`.

Here is what they look like.  The "plain" version is the lower one.
[image]

If you are just starting out you should probably stick with `tabular`, but if you want to really understand TeX I recommend reading the TeXbook thoroughly.  Chapter 22 covers alignments.

Comment: Recommending chapter 20 to someone who is asking about how to center a table is very, very close to sadism :-)

Comment: Reading anything by DEK is pure pleasure! :-)